# 8-bit checksum is off by one

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, checksum

Need help figuring out an 8-bit checksum. The data is 132byte vectors. I thought I had the checksum figured out as I am able to transfer ~30kb of data before I hit the last segment of data shown blow which the checksum fails on. Its off by one.

```
d1 = [0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x10, 0x11, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x10, 0x12, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x10, 0x13, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x10, 0x14, 0xff, 0x00, 0x10, 0x18, 0xff, 0x00, 0x10, 0x1c, 0xff, 0x00, 0x10, 0x20, 0xff, 0x00, 0x10, 0x24, 0xff, 0x00, 0x10, 0x28, 0xff, 0x00, 0x10, 0x2c, 0xff, 0x00, 0x10, 0x30, 0xff, 0x00, 0x10, 0x34, 0xff, 0x00, 0x10, 0x38, 0xff, 0x00, 0x10, 0x3c, 0xff, 0x00, 0x10, 0x40, 0xff, 0x00, 0x10, 0x44, 0xff, 0x00, 0x10, 0x48, 0xff, 0x00, 0x10, 0x4c, 0xff, 0x00, 0x10, 0x50, 0x00, 0x08]
d2 = [0x00, 0x08, 0xff, 0x00, 0x10, 0x54, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x3d, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x0d, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x19, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x49, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x25, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x42, 0x8d, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x31, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x10]
d3 = [0x00, 0xd0, 0xb3, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x62, 0x01, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x61, 0x00, 0xf0, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x80, 0x03, 0x74, 0x21, 0x20, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x91, 0xf0, 0x55, 0x55, 0xe0, 0x80, 0x03, 0x96, 0x21, 0x20, 0x20, 0xb0, 0xb0, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x62, 0x01, 0xf0, 0x00, 0xe1, 0x00, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xe0, 0x80, 0x03, 0x96, 0x21, 0x20, 0x23, 0xb0, 0xb3, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x62, 0x01, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x61, 0x00, 0xf0, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x80, 0x03, 0x96, 0x21, 0x20, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x91, 0xf0, 0x55, 0x55, 0xe0, 0x80, 0x03, 0x94, 0x21, 0x20, 0x20, 0xb0, 0xb0, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x62, 0x01, 0xf0, 0x00, 0xe1, 0x00, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0xe0, 0x80, 0x03, 0x94, 0x21, 0x20, 0x23, 0xb0, 0xb3, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x62, 0x01, 0xf0, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x80, 0x03, 0x94, 0x61, 0x00, 0x21, 0x20, 0xb0, 0x82, 0x00, 0x04, 0xe0, 0x00, 0xc8, 0x00, 0x00, 0xd8]
d4 = [0x00, 0xd8, 0xa0, 0x2c, 0xff, 0x96, 0x7e, 0x21, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x2e, 0xef, 0x1f, 0xce, 0x2e, 0x7f, 0xf0, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x80, 0x04, 0x10, 0x20, 0x90, 0x50, 0x59, 0xb0, 0xa0, 0x00, 0x05, 0xe0, 0x00, 0xc5, 0x00, 0xa0, 0x2c, 0xff, 0x96, 0x7e, 0x19, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x7f, 0x05, 0xf0, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x80, 0x04, 0x10, 0x21, 0x90, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x81, 0xc1, 0x00, 0xbf, 0x21, 0x00, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x2e, 0xef, 0x1f, 0xce, 0x2e, 0x7f, 0xf0, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x80, 0x00, 0x04, 0x20, 0x90, 0x61, 0x07, 0xb0, 0x01, 0x00, 0x04, 0xe0, 0x00, 0xc9, 0x00, 0xa0, 0x2c, 0xff, 0x96, 0x7e, 0x0c, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x2e, 0xef, 0x1f, 0xce, 0x2e, 0x7f, 0xf0, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x00, 0xcb, 0x00, 0xa0, 0x2c, 0xff, 0x96, 0x7e, 0x11, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x2e, 0xef, 0x1f, 0xce, 0x2e, 0x7f, 0xf0, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x00, 0xe1, 0x00, 0xa0, 0x2c, 0xff, 0x96, 0x00, 0xe0]
d5 = [0x03, 0x80, 0x40, 0xff, 0x20, 0x01, 0xfe, 0x00, 0x00, 0x79, 0x49, 0x01, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x80, 0x49, 0x00, 0x03, 0x7c, 0xf5, 0x2e, 0xef, 0x29, 0xef, 0x28, 0xef, 0x1f, 0xce, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x28, 0x7f, 0x29, 0x7f, 0x2e, 0x7f, 0x69, 0x00, 0x7f, 0x0b, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x98, 0xc9, 0x00, 0x02, 0xe0, 0x80, 0x61, 0xa8, 0x08, 0xa0, 0xf0, 0x00, 0xfe, 0x00, 0x00, 0x6a, 0x20, 0xc8, 0x20, 0x90, 0xb0, 0x80, 0x00, 0x03, 0x21, 0xc8, 0x20, 0x91, 0x40, 0xff, 0x20, 0x01, 0xfe, 0x00, 0x00, 0x68, 0x49, 0x01, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x80, 0x49, 0x00, 0x02, 0x7c, 0xf5, 0x2e, 0xef, 0x29, 0xef, 0x28, 0xef, 0x1f, 0xce, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x2e, 0x7f, 0x7e, 0x1b, 0x61, 0x01, 0xf0, 0x00, 0xb0, 0x01, 0x00, 0x17, 0xe0, 0x80, 0x07, 0xe2, 0x21, 0x90, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x81, 0xc1, 0x00, 0xef, 0x21, 0x00, 0x21, 0x90, 0x81, 0xe1, 0x00, 0x10, 0x03, 0x88]
d6 = [0x03, 0x90, 0x20, 0x29, 0x21, 0xb9, 0x42, 0x01, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x80, 0xc1, 0xff, 0x00, 0x50, 0x28, 0x20, 0x08, 0xa1, 0x08, 0x00, 0x01, 0x48, 0x02, 0x49, 0x02, 0x80, 0x42, 0x00, 0x80, 0x7c, 0xf8, 0x60, 0x01, 0x2e, 0xef, 0x29, 0xef, 0x28, 0xef, 0x1f, 0xce, 0x28, 0x7f, 0x18, 0x85, 0x29, 0x7f, 0x19, 0x84, 0x2e, 0x7f, 0x7e, 0xe7, 0x61, 0x01, 0xf0, 0x00, 0xb0, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x60, 0x00, 0x7f, 0x08, 0x90, 0xf0, 0x40, 0x40, 0x20, 0x29, 0x20, 0x98, 0xa1, 0x98, 0x00, 0x01, 0x64, 0x02, 0x50, 0x48, 0x00, 0xe1, 0x20, 0x29, 0xfe, 0xff, 0xf9, 0x6b, 0x60, 0x01, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x2e, 0xef, 0x29, 0xef, 0x28, 0xef, 0x1f, 0xce, 0x2e, 0x7f, 0xf0, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x80, 0x07, 0xe1, 0x20, 0x90, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x91, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x80, 0x80, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x80, 0xb0, 0x11, 0x00, 0x08, 0xe0, 0x80, 0x07, 0xe1, 0x03, 0x98]
d7 = [0x07, 0xa0, 0xa1, 0x0c, 0xc2, 0x5b, 0xa1, 0x0c, 0xc1, 0x8f, 0x81, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x01, 0x51, 0x58, 0x50, 0x21, 0x51, 0x38, 0xf0, 0x00, 0xa1, 0x0c, 0xc1, 0x5b, 0xa1, 0x0c, 0xc1, 0x5c, 0x81, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x01, 0x51, 0x58, 0x50, 0x21, 0x51, 0x38, 0xf0, 0x00, 0xa1, 0x0c, 0xc3, 0xbd, 0xa1, 0x0c, 0xc3, 0xbe, 0x81, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x01, 0x51, 0x58, 0x51, 0x38, 0xa1, 0x0c, 0xc1, 0xb7, 0xa1, 0x0c, 0xc3, 0x40, 0xe1, 0x02, 0x58, 0xe4, 0x50, 0x21, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x80, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x01, 0x50, 0x58, 0x50, 0x38, 0xa0, 0x0c, 0xc3, 0x72, 0xa0, 0x0c, 0xc4, 0x24, 0x10, 0x82, 0x00, 0xa1, 0x20, 0xc0, 0x20, 0x90, 0x81, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x01, 0x51, 0x58, 0x50, 0x01, 0x51, 0x38, 0xf0, 0x00, 0xa1, 0x0c, 0xc2, 0xe6, 0xa1, 0x0c, 0xc2, 0xe7, 0x81, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x01, 0x51, 0x58, 0x50, 0x21, 0x51, 0x38, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x07, 0xa8]
d8 = [0x07, 0xa8, 0xa1, 0x0c, 0xc2, 0xca, 0xa1, 0x0c, 0xc2, 0xcb, 0x81, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x01, 0x51, 0x58, 0x50, 0x21, 0x51, 0x38, 0xf0, 0x00, 0xa1, 0x0c, 0xc1, 0xb6, 0xa1, 0x0c, 0xc1, 0xb8, 0x81, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x01, 0x51, 0x58, 0x50, 0x21, 0x51, 0x38, 0xf0, 0x00, 0xa1, 0x0c, 0xc1, 0xce, 0xa1, 0x0c, 0xc1, 0xcf, 0x81, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x01, 0x51, 0x58, 0x51, 0x38, 0xa1, 0x0c, 0xc1, 0xd2, 0xa1, 0x0c, 0xc1, 0xd3, 0xe1, 0x02, 0x58, 0xec, 0x50, 0x21, 0x50, 0x21, 0x50, 0x21, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x80, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x01, 0x50, 0x58, 0x50, 0x38, 0xa0, 0x0c, 0xc3, 0x29, 0xa0, 0x0c, 0xc3, 0x2b, 0x10, 0x82, 0x00, 0xa1, 0x20, 0xc0, 0x20, 0x90, 0x81, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x01, 0x51, 0x58, 0x50, 0x01, 0x51, 0x38, 0xf0, 0x00, 0xa1, 0x0c, 0xc2, 0x02, 0xa1, 0x0c, 0xc2, 0x04, 0x81, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x01, 0x51, 0x58, 0x50, 0x21, 0x07, 0xb0]

data = [d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8]
correct_checksums = [0xdc, 0xd3, 0xd0, 0xc8, 0xcd, 0xcd, 0xcc, 0xcd]

def checksum8bitHonda(data):
    return ((sum(bytearray(data)) ^ 0xFF) + 1) & 0xFF

def checksum8bit(data):
    return 0xff - (sum(data) >> 8)

checksum_functions = [checksum8bit]
answers = [[] for _ in checksum_functions]

for i,d in enumerate(data):
    print("-----------------------------")
    print(d)
    for j,f in enumerate(checksum_functions):
        c = f(d)
        answers[j].append(c==correct_checksums[i])
        print("%02x" % correct_checksums[i], "%02x" % c, c==correct_checksums[i])

print("")
for a in answers:
    print(a,all(a))
```

Output:

```
-----------------------------
[0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 68, 112, 0, 112, 0, 112, 0, 112, 0, 112, 0, 112, 0, 255, 0, 16, 17, 112, 0, 112, 0, 112, 0, 112, 0, 112, 0, 112, 0, 255, 0, 16, 18, 112, 0, 112, 0, 112, 0, 112, 0, 112, 0, 112, 0, 255, 0, 16, 19, 112, 0, 112, 0, 112, 0, 112, 0, 112, 0, 112, 0, 255, 0, 16, 20, 255, 0, 16, 24, 255, 0, 16, 28, 255, 0, 16, 32, 255, 0, 16, 36, 255, 0, 16, 40, 255, 0, 16, 44, 255, 0, 16, 48, 255, 0, 16, 52, 255, 0, 16, 56, 255, 0, 16, 60, 255, 0, 16, 64, 255, 0, 16, 68, 255, 0, 16, 72, 255, 0, 16, 76, 255, 0, 16, 80, 0, 8]
('dc', 'dc', True)
-----------------------------
[0, 8, 255, 0, 16, 84, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 64, 61, 0, 0, 64, 13, 0, 0, 68, 244, 0, 0, 64, 1, 0, 0, 68, 244, 0, 0, 68, 244, 0, 0, 68, 244, 0, 0, 64, 25, 0, 0, 64, 73, 0, 0, 68, 244, 0, 0, 68, 244, 0, 0, 68, 244, 0, 0, 68, 244, 0, 0, 68, 244, 0, 0, 68, 244, 0, 0, 68, 244, 0, 0, 64, 37, 0, 0, 68, 244, 0, 0, 66, 141, 0, 0, 68, 244, 0, 0, 68, 244, 0, 0, 68, 244, 0, 0, 64, 49, 0, 0, 68, 244, 0, 0, 68, 244, 0, 0, 68, 244, 0, 0, 68, 244, 0, 16]
('d3', 'd3', True)
-----------------------------
[0, 208, 179, 1, 0, 2, 98, 1, 240, 0, 97, 0, 240, 0, 224, 128, 3, 116, 33, 32, 240, 0, 145, 240, 85, 85, 224, 128, 3, 150, 33, 32, 32, 176, 176, 1, 0, 2, 98, 1, 240, 0, 225, 0, 170, 170, 224, 128, 3, 150, 33, 32, 35, 176, 179, 1, 0, 2, 98, 1, 240, 0, 97, 0, 240, 0, 224, 128, 3, 150, 33, 32, 240, 0, 145, 240, 85, 85, 224, 128, 3, 148, 33, 32, 32, 176, 176, 1, 0, 2, 98, 1, 240, 0, 225, 0, 170, 170, 224, 128, 3, 148, 33, 32, 35, 176, 179, 1, 0, 2, 98, 1, 240, 0, 224, 128, 3, 148, 97, 0, 33, 32, 176, 130, 0, 4, 224, 0, 200, 0, 0, 216]
('d0', 'd0', True)
-----------------------------
[0, 216, 160, 44, 255, 150, 126, 33, 240, 0, 46, 239, 31, 206, 46, 127, 240, 0, 224, 128, 4, 16, 32, 144, 80, 89, 176, 160, 0, 5, 224, 0, 197, 0, 160, 44, 255, 150, 126, 25, 240, 0, 127, 5, 240, 0, 224, 128, 4, 16, 33, 144, 240, 0, 129, 193, 0, 191, 33, 0, 240, 0, 46, 239, 31, 206, 46, 127, 240, 0, 224, 128, 0, 4, 32, 144, 97, 7, 176, 1, 0, 4, 224, 0, 201, 0, 160, 44, 255, 150, 126, 12, 240, 0, 46, 239, 31, 206, 46, 127, 240, 0, 224, 0, 203, 0, 160, 44, 255, 150, 126, 17, 240, 0, 46, 239, 31, 206, 46, 127, 240, 0, 224, 0, 225, 0, 160, 44, 255, 150, 0, 224]
('c8', 'c8', True)
-----------------------------
[3, 128, 64, 255, 32, 1, 254, 0, 0, 121, 73, 1, 240, 0, 128, 73, 0, 3, 124, 245, 46, 239, 41, 239, 40, 239, 31, 206, 240, 0, 40, 127, 41, 127, 46, 127, 105, 0, 127, 11, 240, 0, 152, 201, 0, 2, 224, 128, 97, 168, 8, 160, 240, 0, 254, 0, 0, 106, 32, 200, 32, 144, 176, 128, 0, 3, 33, 200, 32, 145, 64, 255, 32, 1, 254, 0, 0, 104, 73, 1, 240, 0, 128, 73, 0, 2, 124, 245, 46, 239, 41, 239, 40, 239, 31, 206, 240, 0, 46, 127, 126, 27, 97, 1, 240, 0, 176, 1, 0, 23, 224, 128, 7, 226, 33, 144, 240, 0, 129, 193, 0, 239, 33, 0, 33, 144, 129, 225, 0, 16, 3, 136]
('cd', 'cd', True)
-----------------------------
[3, 144, 32, 41, 33, 185, 66, 1, 240, 0, 128, 193, 255, 0, 80, 40, 32, 8, 161, 8, 0, 1, 72, 2, 73, 2, 128, 66, 0, 128, 124, 248, 96, 1, 46, 239, 41, 239, 40, 239, 31, 206, 40, 127, 24, 133, 41, 127, 25, 132, 46, 127, 126, 231, 97, 1, 240, 0, 176, 1, 0, 2, 96, 0, 127, 8, 144, 240, 64, 64, 32, 41, 32, 152, 161, 152, 0, 1, 100, 2, 80, 72, 0, 225, 32, 41, 254, 255, 249, 107, 96, 1, 240, 0, 46, 239, 41, 239, 40, 239, 31, 206, 46, 127, 240, 0, 224, 128, 7, 225, 32, 144, 240, 0, 145, 240, 0, 128, 128, 192, 0, 128, 176, 17, 0, 8, 224, 128, 7, 225, 3, 152]
('cd', 'cd', True)
-----------------------------
[7, 160, 161, 12, 194, 91, 161, 12, 193, 143, 129, 192, 0, 1, 81, 88, 80, 33, 81, 56, 240, 0, 161, 12, 193, 91, 161, 12, 193, 92, 129, 192, 0, 1, 81, 88, 80, 33, 81, 56, 240, 0, 161, 12, 195, 189, 161, 12, 195, 190, 129, 192, 0, 1, 81, 88, 81, 56, 161, 12, 193, 183, 161, 12, 195, 64, 225, 2, 88, 228, 80, 33, 240, 0, 128, 192, 0, 1, 80, 88, 80, 56, 160, 12, 195, 114, 160, 12, 196, 36, 16, 130, 0, 161, 32, 192, 32, 144, 129, 192, 0, 1, 81, 88, 80, 1, 81, 56, 240, 0, 161, 12, 194, 230, 161, 12, 194, 231, 129, 192, 0, 1, 81, 88, 80, 33, 81, 56, 240, 0, 7, 168]
('cc', 'cc', True)
-----------------------------
[7, 168, 161, 12, 194, 202, 161, 12, 194, 203, 129, 192, 0, 1, 81, 88, 80, 33, 81, 56, 240, 0, 161, 12, 193, 182, 161, 12, 193, 184, 129, 192, 0, 1, 81, 88, 80, 33, 81, 56, 240, 0, 161, 12, 193, 206, 161, 12, 193, 207, 129, 192, 0, 1, 81, 88, 81, 56, 161, 12, 193, 210, 161, 12, 193, 211, 225, 2, 88, 236, 80, 33, 80, 33, 80, 33, 240, 0, 128, 192, 0, 1, 80, 88, 80, 56, 160, 12, 195, 41, 160, 12, 195, 43, 16, 130, 0, 161, 32, 192, 32, 144, 129, 192, 0, 1, 81, 88, 80, 1, 81, 56, 240, 0, 161, 12, 194, 2, 161, 12, 194, 4, 129, 192, 0, 1, 81, 88, 80, 33, 7, 176]
('cd', 'cc', False)

([True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False], False)
```

Comment: What data type does sum() produce? what data type does hex() expect for an input?

Comment: I've updated the post to include better example data/code. The sum function is expecting an array of ints. hex() just converts the ints to a hex string, its unimportant in this example

Comment: Is there any more specific hint about what the checksum algorithm might be?

Comment: No clue. I am trying to reverse engineer a communications protocol from some packet captures and this is the last piece of the puzzle. All I can do is provide more example data segments and the correct checksum. The comms protocol is the Honda motorcycle K-line interface to the ECU if that helps.

Comment: Actually, the checksum below might act as a hint. It is used in many other places in the code:

((sum(data) ^ 0xFF) + 1) & 0xFF

Comment: That is what I expected it to be since it is the most common 8bit checksum, however it does not match any of the expected results here (not even close) so this is quite confusing. So then I thought perhaps it is the upper byte of the related 16bit checksum ie `(-sum(data) >> 8) & 0xff` but that does not always work either.

Comment: I suspect the data is partitioned in some way as it seems like the checksums I come up with are always off by 1 or 2.

Comment: I have an idea, but I'd like to see more test strings to check it. Also, can you double-check that the checksum of the message consisting of 0xff only is 0x7e? It seems to be the only outlier.

Comment: It will help in particular, if you find examples that fail with `mysteryChecksum2()`.

Comment: Are there any examples/patterns, in particular, you would like me to test. I have an idea for a few new ones that I am about to run shortly.

Comment: @LeoK the checksum for all 0xff was wrong, it should be 0x7f

Comment: Perfect, that is what I figured it should be. If you have more string->checksum pairs that I can test, let me know. Otherwise I could just post my current hypothesis as an answer.

Comment: Gonna be another hour I need to redo my test, the data I injected into the file before transfter was off by 1 so the packets were not filled the way I wanted. Need to redo this. If you want to post your answer I can try testing it while this next batch of data is collected.

Comment: It might be useful to know the 128 checksums of `0x0 0x0 ... 0x0 0x1 0x0 ... 0x0`, with `0x1` sliding around from the first until the last position.

Comment: As would something like `0xFF 0xFF ... 0xFF 0x1 0xFF ... 0xFF` so that you can test if the checksum cares about the order of the bytes or not. How does the checksum handle a single byte in a data chunk changing by 1 or -1? What about single bits being flipped in a single byte?

Comment: @blender good call on the sliding 0x01, the most recent write just finished so I can  try some of those

Comment: So it looks like the correct answer is mysteryChecksum2(). The problem was that I was not passing all the data that I needed to into this function. In the data section of the message that I am trying to figure out there are 2bytes start address, 128butes data, 2bytes end address followed by 2 checksums. The second checksum goes over the 128data plus the address and it seems like so does the first one. I am not sure why I decided to try only the data.

Comment: **Are you sure the package consists of only one part?** Which section do you compare the CRC value to? I think you should read the protocol files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer for the mystery checksum ended up being the function below:

```
def checksum8bit(data):
    return 0xff - ((sum(data))-1) >> 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the checksum is close to what you thought it were (the inverted high-order bits of sum(data)), but corrected with bit 7 of that sum, as follows:

- add all the 128 bytes (max possible value 0x7f80)
- get the high-order bits (15..8) of the sum, that is `a = sum>>8`.
- if bit 7 of the sum is 1, add 1 to a: a += (sum&0xff) >> 7
- invert the result: `return a ^ 0xff`

Or, simpler, using addition of a constant to account for bit 7 correction:

```
def cshc(data):
    s = sum(data) + 0x80
    h = s >> 8
    return h ^ 0xff
```

This gives correct answers for all of the samples you provided (there are only two that have bit7 of the sum equal to 1, so I can't confirm that adding 0x80 is the exact correction needed, try it out with more samples and print both the computed final checksum and the value of `sum(data)&0xff` to see that this is indeed the correct way to do it.

Comment: This looks like its 99% there. I updated the example with some new data. Seems like your algo is working with values <0x80 but =0x80 it fails. The next set of set data should include all 0x81

Comment: The alternative version you listed with the >> 7 failed on 0x80 passed/failed the same tests as cshc()

Comment: the 'alternative' is not different, it should always give the same exact result as cshc(), just how I thought it up originally (as a correction). If you have ability to try out arbitrary data, test these five: [ 7f, 0, 0, 0, ... ] [ 7f, 1, 0, ...], [ 7f, 7f, 0, ... ] [ 7f, 80, 0, 0, ... ] [ 7f, 81, 0, ... ]. Seems like the bytes are being treated as signed (but not exactly as the usual 2-s complement signed - from the one failing test, I can't figure it out yet)